# Database trigger in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, triggers

In my spring project I use the @Entity annotation and let hibernate create the database tables automatically. Now I need some trigger on my database. Since you cannot combine letting Hibernate create the schema and initializing the schema via schema.sql I don't know how to create database trigger. I cannot create trigger in the schema.sql because the table is created afterwards by hibernate.
Since I dont want to rewrite the whole project, I was wondering HOW TO CREATE DATABASE TRIGGER ON JAVA LEVEL. 
What would be the professional way? Would be nice if you could provide a simple code example

I tried @EntityListener but you cannot inject crudrepositories, this option might not be the best. Thats why I'm looking for other solutions.

Comment: Hi, what Java and Spring version are you using?

Comment: Java 8 and Springboot version 2.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: Ok, and what kind of trigger you are looking for? INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE?

Comment: All of them would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several options if you are **absolutely** sure that triggers are what you need.

First of all, there is no "Java way" for creating triggers, at least not that I am aware of. You could implement something like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JDBC_How_to/Statement/Create_triggers_with_multiple_statements_for_mysql_using_jdbc_driver.htm) though, but it would be much more complicated than simply maintaining the triggers definition in SQL statements files and applying them whenever is needed.

Second, why the need to create triggers with Spring? Triggers are not more than code that represent encapsulate some business logic. As such, it might be a good idea to maintain them in separate SQL files and apply them whenever trigger's code is updated. If what you are looking for is to apply them automatically, you can should look for tools like [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) that enables these kind of automated tasks.

If you insist on applying triggers with Spring, then you might consider using the [automatic database initialization provided by Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc), which can run automatically SQL files containing DDL/DML statements. For example, if you use MySQL you might have file called `schema-mysql.sql` under Spring `src/main/resources` folder with your triggers definitions. Note that this will execute the SQL files **everytime** the application starts, so you will have to control such cases with the specifics statements of your database, like `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS my_trigger;` for the case of MySQL.

In my pasts experiences, whenever we needed to use triggers we simply maintained them in separate SQL files, and apply them automatically using Liquibase, but this was in rare occasions given that using triggers highly couples you to the database vendor, which brings to the table other kinds of problems.

Comment: Thanks for you response! I would love to write the triggers in plain SQL, the idea behind writing them in java was that you cannot mix up the database initialization via schema.sql and hibernate creation of the schema. 
so in your opinion i should stick with hibernate creation and then load the triggers from a sql file after starting the application with a tool, e.g. liquibase?

Comment: Yeap, that's the way at least I have been handling these cases. Be careful though, because you will reach a point where automatic schema creation through Hibernate won't be able to update your database properly - most simple case is when you delete a field in an Entity, Hibernate won't delete the column in the database. When you reach that point, you should consider running all your schema updates through a controlled process, like with Liquibase.

Comment: Thank you for the information! what would be the professional/commerical way to set up the database in a project from scratch? Creating the database completely detached from the web-app in workbench/datagrip etc. and then connecting it?

Comment: There isn't a standard or correct way of doing things; "no silver bullet" as Freed Brooks said once long ago :)
The strategy that worked for me is the following: 1) start development delegating the schema generation to the ORM (a "create" or "create-drop" value in the schema generation). 2) As soon as you will deploy in a production like environment, you should stop the automatic schema generation and start running all schema updates through versioned SQL scripts. 3) work to automate schema updates with tools like Liquibase.